# Graphics mode using Assembly in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, graphics

I used functions like this in 2018 (it seems to be Windows XP or 7, Intel processor).
Maybe something is missing here.

1. How to make this work?

Visual Studio 2022
Compiler version: 1933
C++ project
Windows 11 Home 22H2
AMD Ryzen 5 5500U

2. What does this code do at the processor instruction level?
3. Is there an easier way to draw pixel by pixel without using libraries?

```
void SetGr( void )
{
  asm mov AX, 0x13
  asm int 0x10
}

void CloseGr( void )
{
  asm mov AX, 3
  asm int 0x10
}

void PutPixel( int x, int y, int color )
{
  *(unsigned char *)(0xA0000000UL + y * 320U + x) = color;
}
```

I understand that most likely this code is incorrect, and I fully rely on the community's help.
I don't know assembler.
I would like to launch a graphics mode and use it to study computer graphics.

Comment: Modern operating systems do not give direct access to the graphics hardware (or any hardware where they can avoid it) so you're going to have to add some details to the question. The target OS, for one thing, but it would also be good to confirm you're talking Intel assembly.

Comment: I know for a fact that Windows has changed several times, maybe even removing your code's API.  You are going to need to go through hoops in order to use graphics in Windows.  I recommend upgrading your program to use a GUI framework, that can easily adjust when Windows upgrades. :-)

Comment: Recommendation: Start with a framework like [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) and as you get more familiar with it learn about it's underbelly and ultimately work your way down to the hardware interface.

Comment: Your program activates a specific kind of graphics card.  You'll need to do more research to find out which graphics cards support the DOS interrupt system and the parameters.    One problem is that when graphics cards update, your interface may no longer be supported.  Not a good way to study computer graphics.  Use a graphics library or a GUI framework.

Comment: Your code uses *BIOS interrupts* to control a graphics card. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H.

Comment: `int 0x10` will only work in 16-bit real mode.  That code in a Windows executable will just crash; it's not an ABI provided by the Windows kernel for Windows programs.  It looks like generic VGA (@ThomasMatthews) to set a graphics mode with the framebuffer at a known linear address, and then an assignment into video RAM (which could perhaps get optimized away since it's not `volatile`, like if you stored different colors to the same pixel in a loop.)  This graphics feature is baseline for IBM PCs in legacy 16-bit mode, but Windows programs don't run in that mode.

Comment: "I would like to launch a graphics mode and use it to study computer graphics." Well, if you're a time traveler from 1989, sure, but otherwise, you're way off the mark here. Why not learn Vulkan, Metal, or even OpenGL? You can't do much with banging around in the video buffer directly unless you're a demoscene coder. Seeing Visual Studio 2022 and DOS graphics code in the same question is a real trip.

Comment: *I used this code for a long time* -- Do you really mean "I used this code a long time *ago*"?  That code hasn't worked out of the box in a modern OS in maybe 2 decades.

Comment: @OP -- Here are a few questions: 1) When did you last use this code where it worked?  2) What operating system were you using where this worked?  3) What environment (16-bit, 32-bit, etc.) did you see this code last work?  4) What compiler and version of the compiler did you use where your code worked?  5) What model of graphics card were you using where this code worked?  The reason for these questions is because it is curious (at least to me) that it is just now you're realizing the code doesn't work.  You must have been using an ancient OS or computer the last time the code worked.

Comment: if you can target 16 bit MS-DOS executables you could compile and run in DOS-BOX or Virtual machine other than that you out of luck as any modern OS like Win overides BIOS calls completely so this api no longer works (last windows where this works was w9x, In XP this might work but just barely in some compatibility mode but I not sure and really doubt it). Also modern gfx cards usually just emulates this (just to make possible to run BIOS or old VGA based self contained OS like utilities) modern graphics requires usage of gfx API from OS so your options on windows are GL,DirectX or GDI